# HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required?

Tags: windows, networking, router, internet-explorer-8, authentication

When I try to login into our Thomson SpeedTouch router using IE8, I get the following error :

> HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required

The prompt act like I have typed a wrong password, it work fine using Firefox and Telnet.

Im not the only one, I can see someone else on [yahoo answers](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090705022046AA4kTAc)

IE8 does not support HTTP 1.0 ? or its a bug ? or what ?

Comment: things i have tried: there is a couple of boxes under advanced settings (use http 1.1...) they dont make differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable digest authentication on your router.  Telnet into the router and enter:

```
[ system config digestauth=disabled ]
```